# enabling new LDAP claims on WSO2 IS from XML file

Tags: wso2

I added a new user attribute to my LDAP schema, and configured user-mgt.xml to support the new custom ObjectClass.

Then I used the Claim Management UI, and managed to succesfully set the new attribute to be displayed and Supported by default.

Now it all works: I checked that the new claim is correctly setup in the registry db, and whenever I edit a user profile I can view and edit the new custom attribute.

The question is: Can I set this straight up from some xml configuration file?

My problem is that even I edit claim-config.xml and change the parameters to the corresponding claim in the http://wso2.org/claims dialect to be Supported, and give it a DisplayOrder, it has no effect.

I would like not to depend much on the GUI and registry status, but rather rely on configuration files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not edit claim-config.xml file add new claims, if the server has been started once. Only 1st startup, it would populate all claims in to the database (you can delete the database and edit the file and start,  then also it would populate).  Then you can only edit or add them through management console UI.  However, if you know about Identity Server, all these UI functions have been exposed via web service API.  If you does not like UI, you can do it using automating web service call...  Basically SOAPUI can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Could you please provide steps for "Therefore you want to do the claim mapping for correct attribute in the LDAP.  Mostly user object class in the LDAP is created with inetOrgPerson  object..   Therefore you  need to map with the attribute that is supported with inetOrgPerson object class"? We're really facing problem in doing that.... Regards, Neha